# Refactor Eloquent callbacks

Tags: php, laravel, callback, eloquent

Is there a way to refactor this functions? I want to reuse the repeated code within the callbacks. I have no idea where to start, I not only have thos two methods I have more, it would be helpful to re-use repeated code.

```
public static function addedPaginatedUrls($crawl_id, $cmp_crawl_id) {
    return UrlStatus::paginated($crawl_id)
        ->whereNotIn('url.url', function ($sql) use($cmp_crawl_id) {
            // START REPEATED CODE
            $sql->select('url.url')->from('url_status')
            ->join('url', 'url.id', '=', 'url_status.url_id')
            ->join('crawl', 'crawl.id', '=', 'url_status.crawl_id')
            ->where('url_status.crawl_id', '=', $cmp_crawl_id)
            // END REPEATED CODE
            ->where('url_status.pagination', '<>', '')
            ->whereNotNull('url_status.pagination');
        });
}

public static function addedCanonicalUrls($crawl_id, $cmp_crawl_id) {
    return UrlStatus::canonical($crawl_id)
        ->whereNotIn('url.url', function ($sql) use($cmp_crawl_id) {
            // START REPEATED CODE
            $sql->select('url.url')->from('url_status')
            ->join('url', 'url.id', '=', 'url_status.url_id')
            ->join('crawl', 'crawl.id', '=', 'url_status.crawl_id')
            ->where('url_status.crawl_id', '=', $cmp_crawl_id)
            // END REPEATED CODE
            ->whereNotNull('url_status.canonical');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could create a static method on your model, although I don't know if this makes sense, since I don't know all your app logic.

In your UrlStatus model:

```
public static function repeatedCodeRefractoringNameItWhateverYouWant($sql, $cmp_crawl_id){
    // START REPEATED CODE
    return $sql->select('url.url')->from('url_status')
    ->join('url', 'url.id', '=', 'url_status.url_id')
    ->join('crawl', 'crawl.id', '=', 'url_status.crawl_id')
    ->where('url_status.crawl_id', '=', $cmp_crawl_id);
    // END REPEATED CODE
}
```

Then in your code just call it statically:

```
public static function addedPaginatedUrls($crawl_id, $cmp_crawl_id) {
    return UrlStatus::paginated($crawl_id)
        ->whereNotIn('url.url', function ($sql) use($cmp_crawl_id) {
            // START REPEATED CODE
            UrlStatus::repeatedCodeRefractoringNameItWhateverYouWant($sql, $cmp_crawl_id)
            // END REPEATED CODE
            ->where('url_status.pagination', '<>', '')
            ->whereNotNull('url_status.pagination');
        });
}

public static function addedCanonicalUrls($crawl_id, $cmp_crawl_id) {
    return UrlStatus::canonical($crawl_id)
        ->whereNotIn('url.url', function ($sql) use($cmp_crawl_id) {
            // START REPEATED CODE
            UrlStatus::repeatedCodeRefractoringNameItWhateverYouWant($sql, $cmp_crawl_id)
            // END REPEATED CODE
            ->whereNotNull('url_status.canonical');
        });
}
```

If this repeated code is supposed to be shared, by some or all models, just create a new Model class with this method and extend all of your Models from it